# Can we develop Windows Phone 8 app on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-phone-8

1. Can I develop a Windows Phone 8 application on Windows 7 OS?
2. If yes, what would be the system requirements (both hardware and software) on Windows 7 machine?
3. If no, what would be the system requirements (both hardware and software) on Windows 8 machine?
4. Can I run Windows Phone 8 Emulator on Windows 7 machine? If yes, what would be the system requirements (both hardware and software)?
5. Do I need Zune software to register my Windows Phone 8 to deploy and test my app?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but the Phone Emulator will only work on Windows 8 as far as I know. For *developing* (and testing on a real phone instead of the emulator), Windows 7 works - all you need is either Visual Studio 2012 with the Phone SDK installed, or Visual Studio 2013 (which includes the Phone SDK already). For developing Phone 8.1 apps, VS 2013 is mandatory

In addition, to run the Phone 8 Emulator, check [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_checklist) for the hardware requirements.

I'm not sure about (5) the Zune software, but I think it's not necessary any more with the Phone 8.0 platform.

Comment: The Zune software is not necessary :)